# Java Multi Threading Control

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks

I am using this code to create threads.

```
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                r = new runnable(strLine);
                new Thread(r).start();
                x++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
      }
```

How can I control the maximum number of threads running at any point of time?
This code has issues where memory used keeps rising(memory leak) is there a better way to do this?
I tried using scheduler but didnt help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to create constrained thread pools.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

will create a pool with 10 available threads. You can then call

```
executor.submit(new Runnable() { ... })
```

for each unit of work.

**EDIT**: I should note that this facility is only available in Java 1.5 and later.